# Why is causal influence between concepts in Fuzzy Cognitive maps represented by membership functions?

Tags: fuzzy-logic, causal-diagrams

We Know that FCM are represented by concepts and Weights or causal influence between the concepts. In order to find the weights, we take the help of an expert that describes the relationship between the two concepts using:
1. negative or positive influence
2. Strong, Medium, Weak Influence
Once the relationship is described by taking one option from the each of the two numerical subdivisions above. Based on research papers, each Influence term from negatively weak, negatively medium,.......to positively strong are each represented by triangular(mostly) membership functions.

Can you please help me understand why membership functions are taken to represent the causal relationships as they can just be represented by numeric values between -1 to 1 instead?